# Extracting Image with CSQuery and then inserting it in front of heading tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html, csquery

I was trying to use HTMLAgilityPack to manipulate some Html. I decided to try CSQuery as well.

The goal is to extract and img tag and it src and reinsert it in front of an h3 tag.

Assume html:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content galleryItem">
                    <h3>
                        Al Shabaab kill at least 29 in latest attacks on Kenyan coast                            
                    </h3>           
                   <p> <img alt src="../../../../images/AlShabaab.jpg"></p>
<p>
    Al Shabaab killed at least 29 people in two coastal areas of Kenya.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Goal is to move the img in front of the h3

I used the following to strip the style attr from img tags:

```
   Dim csq = CQ.Create(input)
   Dim csstyle = csq("img")
   Return csstyle.RemoveAttr("style")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not explicitly tag this VB.NET I'll answer in C#, I hope that's OK:

```
var cq = CQ.create(input); // create the CsQuery source
var img = cq["img"]; // image here, img["src"] is its source
img.Remove().InsertBefore(cq["h3"]);// remove it, and add it in front of H3.
```

of course this code can be shorter, but I wanted the code to match your literal description.

Comment: Didn't quite work I think because the img is wrapped by p tags which I forgot to mention.

Comment: For the protocol Changing the question after being answered is considered somewhat impolite in Stack Overflow. That said, the above code should still work and I just tested it. Don't forget to render when you're done processing.